# Changing ListView Color gives weird text on top of list Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of two names placed in the code behind that are binded to a ListView on the xaml file, and after trying to change the name colors to white, I got this on the screen:

[Screenshot of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2JMh.png)

the code: XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="RoseySports.Invite_Page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
               Source="background.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>

                <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">

                <ContentView Padding="10, 40, 10, 10">

                <ListView x:Name="inviteesp" SeparatorColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Header="People">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <TextCell Text="{Binding names}" TextColor="White"/>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </ContentView>
            </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

C# (Code-Behind):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RoseySports
{
    public partial class Invite_Page : ContentPage
    {
        public Invite_Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var names = new List<String>

            {

                "Mohamed Al-Sabbagh",
                "Adrien Tardy"

            };

            inviteesp.ItemsSource = names;
        }
    }
}
```

[After adding the binding source to the ListView property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd8E4.png)

Comment: Is this the xaml live player or is it the iOS simulator? Also one question, probably stupid but I have to ask, you can 100% confirm that the text is not in your background image? Is the problem on Android emulator, too? Also, you shouldn't use list view nested into scrollview. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scroll-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a `Header` which is not shown, but this strange text, I assume the problem is connected with that.
Are you sure you have all NuGet packages and are on the correct NetStandard version?
You should probably check your targeting versions, clean, restore and rebuild your solution.

If this doesn't help try adding an explicit layout for your header like

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Header="TEST HEADER"> <!-- this object will be the bindingcontext -->
  <ListView.HeaderTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding .}"/> <!-- use the object in Header as the binding source -->
      </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    your template goes here
```

please also check out this xamarin forums thread
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/126386/setvalue-can-not-convert-system-readonlyspan-to-type-xamarin-forms-color

Maybe try to update to Xamarin Forms 3 if you haven't already.
Check if there are references to older Xamarin Forms versions in your projects
 files (android, ios, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is correct?

```
{Binding names}
```

Try with

```
{Binding .}
```

Comment: Hello Sir, Can you please explain me the use of '{Binding .}', I searched but I didn't get good answer.

Comment: "." is the object you are binding to ItemSource. In this example inviteesp.ItemsSource = names; so you are binding the "String" (.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` should be bound to `names` and inside of the template just use `{Binding}` to point at the element instead of property of that element.

```
<ListView x:Name="inviteesp" SeparatorColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Header="People" ItemsSource="{Binding names}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding}" TextColor="White"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Currently you're trying to bind each character to each `TextCell` instead of trying to bind each string to each `TextCell`.

Comment: Did what you said, the list showed up in white like I wanted it to, but I'm still getting that weird text on top of the list in black

Comment: @MohamedAlSabbagh Can you edit your question with a screenshot of that?

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: @MohamedAlSabbagh It seems like your page is displayed in some kind of container which is not shown in here.

Comment: Tried removing everything unrelated to the list but it's still giving the error at the top of the page